# Iterating through a for loop and appending results to a react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im curious on how to iterate through an array and append the results to a react component. 
Ive gotten the part of sorting through an array of objects and grabbing the accounts that I want. Now im unsure of how to go about appending them to html.

```
export default class SortedTeams extends React.Component {


  renderContent(content){
    var entries = [{fullname: 'foo', title: 'designer'}, {fullname: 
    'foo2', 
    title: 'designer'}, {fullname: 'foo3', title: 'developer'}]
    var nohit = [];

    for(var i = 0; i <= entries.length - 1; i++) {

      if(entries[i].title === 'designer'){
        console.log('foohit');
  }
      else{
        nohit.push('nope')
   }
  }

  render() {
    var content = this.props.block.content;


    return(
      <SiteBuilderBlock tag="section" className="sortedTeams" block={this.props.block}>
        <div>
        <SiteBuilderList tag="div" list="teams" inGroupsOf={4} inGroupsOfClassName="row">
         {(element, key) => this.renderContent(element, key)}
      </SiteBuilderList>
    </div>

  </SiteBuilderBlock>
);
```

}

}

Comment: On the bus now so can't help much with code but have a look at the map method. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate through an array. In this case `contacts` is an array of objects like `entries`. Here I'm using an ES6 syntax and [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
return(
  <div>
    <ul>
      { contacts.map(contact => (
          <li key={contact.id}>
            {contact}
          </li>
        )
      )}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```